# React delete an item from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, methods, filter

I'm fetching some data from a JSON file. I'm using the map method to display it and it's stored in a state. I need to be able to delete an item when the delete button is clicked. I'm using the filter method to filter out that specific item but I get this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')**

```
export default function Customers() {

const { appData, setAppData } = useContext(AppContext);
const { customers, packages } = appData;


function handleDeleteCustomer(id) {
    
    console.log(id)
    setAppData(setAppData.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id), appData.packages)
}

return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>

                    <TableCell >id</TableCell>
                    <TableCell >Name</TableCell>
                    <TableCell />
                    <TableCell />

                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                {appData.customers.map((row) => {
                    return (
                        <TableRow sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{row.id}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell >{row.name}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell ><Button variant="contained">Create Invoice</Button></TableCell>
                            <TableCell ><Button variant="contained" onClick={() => handleDeleteCustomer(row.id)}>Delete</Button></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    )
                })}
            </TableBody>
        </Table>
    </TableContainer>
)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code:

```
setAppData(appData.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id), appData.packages)
```

not

```
setAppData(setAppData.customers.filter(customer => customer.id !== id), appData.packages)
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it but still got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I think you should check if customers is defined before doing ``` appData.customers.map(...)``` you can do it by simply adding this:
```
!appData.customers ? "no customers" : appData.cutomers.map(...)  
```

Comment: It's defined as long as I don't click the button. The list of customers is rendered. When I click the delete button, then for some reason 'appData.customers' is not defined anymore.

Comment: I believe the error is coming from `setAppData` function.